# Как C++ программу, скомпилированную в CentOS 7, заставить работать в CentOS 6?

Tags: g++, c++, centos

Компьютер разработчика CentOS 7. Как заставить работать скомпилированную C++ программу в CentOS 6? Выдаёт ошибки несоответствия версий библиотек...

Answer (score 2):

Варианты:

1. Разработчик отдает исходники и они компилируются на целевой платформе
2. Разработчик ставит себе в систему библиотеки совместимости с centos 6 и линкуется с ними при компиляции
3. Разработчик ставит себе на машину centos 6 и компилирует бинарник внутри centos 6 (через lxc это сделать относительно просто. Через chroot можно сделать чтобы виртуалка вообще не запускалась, а только использовалось её окружение для компиляции).
4. Компилировать статически (бинарник может стать более увесистым, возможно придется наткнуться на какие-то грабли, например для php скомпилированным статически в окружении centos 5 x86 не работают dns-запросы если запустить его на ubuntu 14.04 x64)

Дальше скорее костыли:

5. Разработчик отдает бинарник вместе с библиотеками, которые ставятся в вашу систему или в окружение (думаю могут быть проблемы аналогичные п.4)
6. Скомпилировать нужные версии библиотек для centos 6 и поставить их в систему.

Answer (score 1):

Если версии библиотек стоят другие, то боюсь, что никак. Если код ссылается на одно, а там другое, то как оно заработает?)

Ставьте одинаковые версии используемых библиотек. Или компилируйте статически (то есть чтобы код библиотеки был в вашей программе и не нуждался в библиотеках системы).

Comment: не все можно скомпилировать статически. Я тут недавно вкомпилил libc и glib статически. Все вроде было хорошо, но когда запустил на целевой платформе, сказало, что ядро очень древнее и работать не буду.

Comment: Да, бывают трудности. Если честно, то делал такое только с Qt, да и то Qt5 статически удалось собрать только в Gentoo, Windows не поддалась. Пожалуй, мне по делу нечего добавить, добивайтесь соответствия библиотек.

Comment: Тоже пытался статически... Не прокатывает. ((( И что делать?

Comment: поставить на виртуалку нужную центось, собрать на ней.

Comment: Была с CentOS 6. Проблема в том, что я использую C++11

Comment: А там такой древний компилятор, что не поддерживает его?

Comment: да, версии 4.4.7... не поддерживает C++11

Comment: @sitev_ru, точно все слинковали статически? Что ldd говорит?

Comment: А Вам действительно нужно что-то из С++11, чего нет в более старом? Может, переписать код под более старый, который будет поддерживаться и там, и там?

Comment: да, нужен C++11... ldd пока не могу показать - отказался от этой идеи

Comment: Остается собрать нужную версию g++ вместе с необходимыми либами из исходников на CentOS 6 :-(